# I can hear the audio, but the video won't play on chrome and firefox

Tags: html, video, video.js

When I click play, I can hear the audio of the video, but I the video doesn't play! I am using video.js for this. here is my code:

HTML

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="501" height="286" poster="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/video.gif" onclick="this.play();"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/video/final.mp4" type='video/mp4'>

</video>
```

and another thing, when I click on the poster, the audio starts but the poster stays. I tried with a smaller poster, and the video sure doesn't play(so that we don't say that the video works but is hidden but the poster)

On Safari, it works perfectly locally. on wordpress, I loose the control bar.
on chrome and firefox, I only hear the audio, the poster stays, the controls do not appear.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your video from? If it is a mainstream website you can get the embed link and include it in your HTML. Don't know what exactly you are working on but this should help.

Comment: it works now, I can see the video, I only had to add a webm type of my video to make it work. But still the controls don't appear! any idea? i am getting the video from the wordpress theme from a 'video' folder.